# In Python, how can I type hint a list with an empty default value?

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, default-arguments

I would like to make a function that looks like this, but I'm aware that default arguments should never be mutable:

```
def foo(req_list: list, opt_list: list = []): 
    ...
```

Without type hinting, I know the way to have an optional parameter default to an empty list is:

```
def bar(req_list, opt_list=None):
    if opt_list == None:
        opt_list = []
    ...
```

But I'm not sure of the correct way to do this with type hinting.

Answer (score 3):

what you have is semantically correct. although I would do this, kind of echoing your second code block.

```
def foo(req_list: list, opt_list: list | None = None):
    if opt_list is None:
        opt_list = []
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I've only recently starting type hinting everything and didn't realize I could put an 'or' in there.